# A menu option that receives input from users and then performs actions

Tags: java, array

Please review my `FindMovie` and `AddMovie` methods.

```
public static boolean FindMovie(String movietofind, String[] ArrayMovie) {
    movie Movieobject = new movie();

    for (String ArrayMovie1 : ArrayMovie) {
        if (ArrayMovie1.equals(movietofind)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void AddMovie(int i, String[] ArrayMovie, String[] UserRating, int[] UserReview) {
    int addmovie, userrating;
    boolean Movie1;
    String MPAA;
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please give me the name of the movie you want to add.");
    String Movie = console.next();

    Movie1 = FindMovie(Movie, ArrayMovie);
    if (Movie1 = false) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to add this movie to the collection? Please select 1 for Yes or 2 for No");
        addmovie = console.nextInt();
        if (addmovie == 1) {
            ArrayMovie[i] = Movie;

            System.out.println("What is the type of MPAA rating of the movie?");
            System.out.println("Please enter G, PG, PG13, or R");
            MPAA = console.next();
            UserRating[i] = MPAA;

            System.out.println("What is your rating for movie?");
            System.out.print("please choose 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5");
            userrating = console.nextInt();
            UserReview[i] = userrating;

        } else if (addmovie == 2) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Technical**

1. Your naming conventions are inconsistent - you mix PascalCase with alllowercase (don't know if that convention has it's own name). In Java types (like classes and interfaces) are PascalCase and method and variable names are camelCase.
2. Declare variables where they are used and not all at the top of the function.
3. `Movie1` one is not a good name for a variable. The variable name should express the meaning of it. In this case it should be `movieExists`.
4. `FindMovie` won't compile due to the first line in the function (there is no `movie` type in your source code and nothing actually references a `movie` type except that one line of code). It should be removed (`Movieobject` is never used)
5. There is no need to prefix the variable name with the type of the variable it just adds clutter and no real value. So `ArrayMovie` should be `movies` as that's what the collection represents (a collection of movies).
6. If you use `ArrayList` instead of arrays you get automatic resizing when adding new movies and a whole bunch of nice utility functions like `contains` which reduce a lot of code clutter and does not impose the limitation of fixed sized arrays.
7. `AddMovie` requires the caller to pass in the index in the array where the movie should be stored. This is bad as it requires the caller to keep information about the structure of the list. It should just add a new movie to the end of a list (see previous point about `ArrayList`).
8. You can reduce nesting by breaking early when hitting the negative condition, for example:

   ```
   bool movieExists = FindMovie(Movie, ArrayMovie);
   if (movieExists)
   {
       return;
   }

   System.out.println("Do you want to add this movie to the collection? Please select 1 for Yes or 2 for No");
   bool userAction = console.nextInt();
   if (userAction != 1)
   {
       return;
   }

   // add the movie
   ```

**Design**

It seems like you had the right idea at some point about having a `movie` class (although it should be named `Movie`) encapsulating the properties of a movie like name, rating and reviews. Right now you seem to pass them around as 3 independent lists and the only connection is that the index in each list refers to the same movie. This is easy to get out of sync and you always have to pass around 3 lists - not to mention what happens when you want to add a 4th or 5th property.

`AddMovie` should just accept an `ArrayList<Movie>` as input to which you can add a new movie after you have gathered all the user input.

Answer (score 2):

Quick pointers:

1. What is the point of `movie Movieobject = new movie();` ?
2. According to Java naming conventions, your use of camel cases is inverted. Variable and method names should start with a lower case, and classes (e.g. `movie`) should start with an upper case.
3. The `for loop` for `findMovie` can be replaced by one line for brevity, although there are still a couple more ways to optimize this part:

   ```
   return Arrays.asList( movieArray ).contains( searchMovie );
   ```
4. Since option 2 is not meant to do anything, there is no need to include

   ```
   } else if (addmovie == 2) {
   ```

   at all.
5. What is the purpose of passing in so many `String` arrays for the `addMovie` method?
6. You can inline the `findMovie` call from this:

   ```
   Movie1 = FindMovie(Movie, ArrayMovie);
   if (Movie1 = false) {
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   if (!findMovie(movie, arrayMovie)) {
   ```

I feel a bit more background to your question is needed here.

Edit: Of course, going by OOP practices, you really should be creating `Movie` instances to check for its existence in the `ArrayList` etc., but I'll defer such bigger changes until there is more information given to support your use cases.